# A question about * property

Tags: general-topology

The topological$(X,\tau)$ spaces has * property if for every cover $U_{i}$ of $X$ there is a finite subfamily $U_{i_{1}},\ldots,U_{i_{n}}$ such that $X=\operatorname{cl}(U_{i_{1}}) \cup \ldots\cup \operatorname{cl}(U_{i_{n}})$. This is the same as saying that the union of $U_{i_{j}}$ is dense in $X$.

**The following example shows a space that has the * property but is not compact.**

> Let $X=[0,1]$ with the topology that has the usual topology union $\{X\setminus A\}$ as a subbase, where $A= \{ 1,1/2, 1/3,\ldots\}$. This makes $A$ closed and discrete in $X$, so $X$ is not compact.
> Now we will check  the property above for  this $X$, Take **cover from a base for the topology of $X$, which is the set of all Euclidian open sets together**  with all sets of the form $\{O\setminus A\}$, where  $O$ is  also Euclidian open. So if We have an open cover $U_{i}$  of $X$ iff **the latter covers $X$, but now with just plain Euclidian open set.** So (by compactness of $X=[0,1]$ in the Euclidian topology) there are finitely many $V_{i_{1}},\ldots,V_{i_{n}}$ that cover $X=[0,1]$. So the corresponding $U_{i_{1}},\ldots,U_{i_{n}}$ cover at least $X=[0,1]\setminus A$ which is **dense in** $X$, as required.

1.I don't understand why the space is not compact, please explain more.

2.In the part that shows that the space has the *property, there are phrases written that I did not understand, such as "**cover from a base for the topology of $X$, which is the set of all Euclidian open sets together** or **just plain Euclidian open set**. Please explain more and better if possible or write it mathematically. Thanks.

Comment: `\setminus` will produce the backslash for set difference.

Comment: Additionally, note that while ````\ldots```` sometimes results in the same result as just ````...```` you should get in the habit of writing it in math mode instead of ````...````.  Compare, for instance, $$X=\operatorname{cl}(U_{i_{1}}) \cup ...\cup \operatorname{cl}(U_{i_{n}})$$ (with ````...````) and
$$X=\operatorname{cl}(U_{i_{1}}) \cup \ldots\cup \operatorname{cl}(U_{i_{n}})$$ (with ````\ldots````)

Comment: Where did this property come from?

Comment: If $A$ closed then its compliment is open. Use that to find a cover that has no finite subcover.

Comment: Where is this example coming from?  Is it your own example, or did you get this from a paper?  If so, please mention a reference.

Answer (score 1):

> This makes $A$ closed and discrete in $X$, so $X$ is not compact

If $X$ is compact, then so is $A$ (because it is closed). $A$ is discrete and infinite, though, so it cannot be compact. That's what they mean.

"Cover from a base for the topology of $X$" means a cover whose every element (an open set) is in $\mathcal{B}$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is a chosen basis for the topology of $X$. Here, that's all sets of the form $U\setminus A$ and all sets of the form $U$ where $U$ is a Euclid**ea**n-open set. It's an open cover which is not allowed to contain sets of any other form.

It suffices to consider such covers since is $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$ then every $x\in X$ is contained in some $V$, where $V$ is a basis set and $V\subseteq U$ for some $U\in\mathscr{U}$. If we can show $X=\operatorname{cl}(V_1)\cup\cdots\cup\operatorname{cl}(V_n)$ for finitely many such $V_\bullet$, then it's definitely true that $X=\operatorname{cl}(U_1)\cup\cdots\cup\operatorname{cl}(U_n)$ for finitely many $U_\bullet\in\mathscr{U}$.